# SSRS reports deployment across different environment using ADO

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-devops, devops

I am able to deploy the ssrs report (.rdl file) to the target server using an azure extension successfully. However now if I have to deploy them to different environments like preprod,prod. I need to manually change the connection string in the .rdl file. How can I automate this process.

Answer (score -1):

In our environments, we set up a DataSource per environment, and then after creating/deploying the report, we set its DataSource to the DataSource for that environment (Note, this is using the legacy SOAP API, this example would need to change if you're using the REST API):

```
param(
    [string]$environment = "",
    [string]$reportServerUri = "https://localhost:443/SSRS"
)

$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $reportServerUri -UseDefaultCredential

$targetFolderPath = ("/ChangeThisRootFolderToWhereverYouWantItToBe/Reports/{0}" -f $environment)
$newDataSourcePath = ("/ChangeThisRootFolderToWhereverYouWantItToBe/DataSources/{0}/ChangeThisDataSource" -f $environment)
$newDataSourceName = "ChangeThisDataSource"
$warnings = $null

Get-ChildItem *.rdl | Foreach-Object {
    $reportName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)
    $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_.FullName)
 
    Write-Output "Uploading report ""$reportName"" to ""$targetFolderPath""...`r`n"
    $warnings = $rs.CreateReport(
        $reportName,      # Report name
        $targetFolderPath,# Destination folder
        $true,            # Overwrite report if it exists?
        $bytes,           # .rdl file contents
        $null)            # Properties to set.

    $warnings | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Output ("Warning: {0}" -f $_.Message)
    }

    $reportPath = "$($targetFolderPath)/$($reportName)"
    $dataSources = $rs.GetItemDataSources($reportPath) 
    $dataSources | ForEach-Object { 
        $proxyNamespace = $_.GetType().Namespace 
        $myDataSource = New-Object ("$proxyNamespace.DataSource") 
        $myDataSource.Name = $newDataSourceName 
        $myDataSource.Item = New-Object ("$proxyNamespace.DataSourceReference") 
        $myDataSource.Item.Reference = $newDataSourcePath 
        $_.item = $myDataSource.Item 
        $rs.SetItemDataSources($reportPath, $_) 
        Write-Output "Changing report's DataSource reference ($($_.Name)) to: $($_.Item.Reference)"; 
    } 
    Write-Output "" 
}
```